# Git -- View merge diff of merge conflict resolution with subsequent commits?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-show

While working on a feature branch, I realized that merging master back into my feature-branch to keep it up to date would require some work and a code-review. So I branched off the feature, merged in master, and made some additional commits on the 'merge-branch'

```
master-A-B-C-H-I-J-K-L
      \
    feature-D-E-F-M
                 \
                  merge-branch
                    + merge master, resolve conflicts
                    + make a few more commits
```

Ok so right off the bat I realize that a rebase would perhaps have been better, but given this scenario, my question is: how do I view the work done in `merge-branch, ie the merge conflict resolution along with the subsequent commits? Is there any way to do this other than commit by commit?

I know `git show` on the merge-commit shows the initial conflict resolution, but ideally I'd like to see that resolution along with the other commits not on `master` or `feature`